# Constructor for http request in Angular using interface

Tags: angular, http, abstract-class, angular-services

I'm trying to create an interface class in angular that can help me create rapid http requests.

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "user.login",
"params": {
    "user": "Admin",
    "password": "zabbix"
},
"id": 1,
"auth": null
}
```

as you can see this is the body of an typical request, I need a constructor that lets me change easily the method ,and params.

```
eimport { Injectable } from '@angular/core';



 export interface AbstractCallsService {
 params: Object
jsonrpc: '2.0',
 method: String
  auth: 'b5298aa8b333e3dbc2ffdea02ddb280a',
id: 1
}
 @Injectable()
 export abstract class CreateReq {
abstract createReq(params , method): AbstractCallsService[]
 }
```

This is what I tried till now, but I can't get to implement this  method

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { AbstractCallsService } from './abstract-calls.service';

@Injectable()
 export class CallerCreateService implements AbstractCallsService {
 method1 = 'host.get';
 params = {output: 'extend', limit : '10'}

 createReq(params1: Object, method1: String) {
 const req: AbstractCallsService = [
 {
  params: params1,
  method: method1
  }
   ];
return req;
 }
 }
```

I'm a total begginer so, any tips are appreciated. The thing i thought about is to create something like 10 classes that implements abstractCallsService and has  a constant METHOD argument in my call and maybe with only one argument in input for the params object
Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { AbstractCallsService } from './abstract-calls.service';

@Injectable()
export class CallerCreateService implements AbstractCallsService {
 method1 = 'host.get';
 params = {output: 'extend', limit : '10'}


 createReq(params1: Object) {
const req: AbstractCallsService = [
 {
 params: params1,
method: this.method1,
  }
  ];
  return req;
 }
 }
```

I come from a Java background so pardon me for this basic errors.

Comment: I'm not much clear about the thing :(

Comment: in a more simple way I want to create an method in angular where you can put one argument inside ,the arguments will be my http request parameters. I wanted to use abstract classes but can't figure it out